# Shadows improperly displayed in React Native application

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, shadow

I am currrently developing React Native application for both Android and iOS and I have encountered behaviour where shadows are improperly displayed on test device. Shadows look fine in Android emulator, however, when I build APK and upload it to test device, the shadows don't display properly anymore. The code working in emulator and code in built apk differ only in api url.

Shadows are set like this:

```
shadowOffset: {
  width: 3,
  height: 3,
},
shadowColor: Color.BLACK, // Resolves to #000000
shadowOpacity: 1,
elevation: 2,
backgroundColor: Color.TRANSPARENT // Resolves to #0000
```

Below I attach also the look on emulator (desired):

[image: Should be]

and look on test device:

[image]

Appreciate any ideas on where to look for possible fix.

I am using React Native 0.63.1 and testing on device with Android 10.